# Color Management: Linear ACES to After Effects

Tags: rendering, color-management

I rendered an animation in blender with the sequencer under color management set to "Linear ACES". I saved them out as an EXR sequence. I was wondering what After Effects color profile I should use to interpret the footage for what Blender calls "Linear ACES" as there is no color profile of the same name in AE. I tried ACEScg and ACEScct to interpret the footage in AE but the colors didn't look right. What color profile is "Linear ACES" technically?

Comment: https://www.toodee.de/?page_id=1720

Comment: https://community.acescentral.com/t/aces-set-up-for-blender-using-ocio/2106

Comment: I actually used ACES OCIO for a little while, but found it cumbersome when choosing color profile for image textures and HDRIs. It seems weird native color management would have Linear ACES without any apparent way to use it.

Comment: OCIO is how color is managed in blender. Note that you can customize OCIO to use whatever color transforms you need by editing the config.ocio file and adding whatever LUTs you want to use.  Most HDRi use sRGB/Rec709 primaries.